# Create a sub network in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

Hello I have the following network setup

[image]

A, B, C and D are pc's with windows installed.
A has internet access via a PCI wifi card and its connection is bridged to the ethernet port and then given to a switch with provides connection to B, C and D.

- I want to block internet access to B, C and D.
- 'A' is part of private network with static ip `192.168.0.xxx` is it possible to create another private network on A, like `10.0.0.x` and then B, C and D become part of this private network.
- I need to do this so that I can install some custom software on A and distribute it to B, C and D so it would be preferred if I can set up fixed static IP's on B, C and D like 10.0.0.10, 10.0.0.20 and so on.

Would this be possible with windows settings itself without installing 3rd party software?

**EDIT**:
Actually I had to bridge the connections because E, F and G require internet access. I had missed that earlier.

- What IP addresses do I assign to B, C, D.
- 'A' already has a wifi NIC and an Inbuilt NIC that are bridged and A belongs to a network 192.168.0.xx
- Connection to A comes from a Wifi router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, turn of the bridging between the wifi and ethernet.

**Update**

I can see two options.

1. Add a second ip address to the bridged interface (such as 10.0.0.1), and IP B, C, and D as you intended.
2. Add another network card to A, and IP it as 10.0.0.1. Connect B, C, D to a new switch, and that extra network card.

Comment: will B, C and D still be connected on LAN to A if I do this?

Comment: Yes, you will just need to give A an ip address on the same subnet that you are giving to B, C, and D

Comment: becomingwisest, I've edited my question regarding why I had to bridge the connection.

Comment: I like option 1, I have some questions, after adding the new ip address to A(`10.0.0.1`) and new Ip adresses to B, C, D in the same range, I don't want B, C and D to have internet access.  Also other computers on the older(`192.168.0.xx`) network should be unable to view B, C and D.  I want to share a folder on A with B, C, and D for this would I need to setup a workgroup or something like that?

Comment: Another Question, As you see in the diagram the switch supplies connections to B, C , D and E, F, G. can the same switch reliably provide data to them even if they are of different IP's as per your plan 1.

Comment: You will need to do testing, and you might need to disable NetBIOS and/or other non-ip abilities of BCD, since all the protection of option 1 is based on ip subnets. If it is just IP traffic, then this will work as simple security. EFG won't by default reach to any IP traffic that BCD send. But either side could be changed by a sys admin, and they would be able to talk to each other. If a sys admin makes changes to BCD, then they could get internet access again.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you bridge the connections in the first place?  If you simply added a nic that had internet access and left the internal nic on the internal network no internaet access would happen from any box other than A

Comment: Jim, I've edited my question regarding why I had to bridge the connection.